# Como posso remover o espaçamento entre métodos e propriedades?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editor-de-texto

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2017 Preview mais atualizado, e já tentei desinstalar e resetar as configurações, porém este espaçamento continua independente do que eu faça.

[image: Espaçamento entre linhas]

Como posso remover isso?

Answer (score 0):

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image]
Normalmente esses "gaps" entre as linhas são "helpers" que o editor mostra, coisas que ele quer mostrar mas que realmente não estão escritos no código.

Verifique suas propriedades e opções de sintax highlight. Pode ser que no seu caso esses "helpers" estejam sendo escritos com a mesma cor de fundo e por isso vc não os veja.

Comment: Pelo que parece também não é isso, botei o tema padrão do Visual Studio e continua na mesma situação.

Comment: @danspark Pode ser a configuração do codelens (esses helpers que vem em algumas versoes do VS). Tente desativar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references

Comment: Realmente, o CodeLens estava ativado em todos os idiomas, porém estava desativado no C#, quando desativei em tudo voltou ao normal, talvez seja algum bug por ser a versão Preview?

Comment: @danspark Vai saber... mas parece que tem como vc mudar as cores do code lens tb que eu tentaria pois quando vc muda o tema muda tudo junto e pode ser que o tema esteja mal configurado